# Regra dupla em LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela notícias com os campos `titulo`, `conteudo` e `destaque`, sendo o destaque int(1), é um valor booleano só para verificar se uma notícia é destaque ou não, o que gostaria de fazer é selecionar uma quantidade de notícias e dentro dessa quantidade X notícias precisam ser destaques (`destaque=1`), algo como isso:

```
SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE destaque = 1 limit 5 AND ... LIMIT 30.
```

Ou seja, 30 notícias, sendo 5 delas destaques e o resto (25) "comuns".

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pegue as 5 que precisa de um critério, ou seja, que sejam destaque, e depois pegue outras 25 que não precisam deste critério.

```
SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE destaque = 1 limit 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE destaque <> 1 limit 25
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Union3.sql).

Duvido que esta seja uma consulta que produza um resultado interessante, mas atende ao critério colocado na pergunta.

Comment: Eu ainda colocaria `UNION ALL` já que todos os resultados serão garantidamente distintos

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado vê alguma vantagem? Será que otimiza?

Comment: Sobre "...Consulta produza um resultado interessante", existem soluções melhores? fazer cada query separada?

Comment: Não sei, só você sabe o que você deseja, mas é provável que exista, afinal pegar coisas soltas assim do banco de dados dificilmente será algo útil e provavelmente virá sempre as mesmas coisas (excetuando provavelmente os destaques se eles forem sendo trocados ao longo do tempo, mas as outras notícias nunca mudarão, portando não serão exatamente notícias)

Comment: Entendi, mas eu colocaria para filtrar pelo ID

Comment: Isto não está na sua pergunta.

Comment: Mas não seria só colocar o ORDER BY id ASC/DESC ao final da instrução?